# How do I set an environment variable for GitHub repositorys?

Tags: github, oauth-2.0, environment-variables, repository, discord.js

So I'm creating a website in a GitHub repo, on which I'm trying to implement a Discord Login via OAuth2. For all that to work I need to set an environment variable for the client id and secret. How do I set an environment variable in a GitHub repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I set an env var in a github repo

Env vars are only relevant to the machine actually running the bot (or website).

Most hosting companies today give you a way to edit your environment variables. If you are using github as a webhost, maybe see [this github article](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/using-environment-variables).

Let's say you have a string which needs to be in a variable `token`. For your local development, you create a file that simply sets that variable. Make sure to exclude it from `git` by including it in your `.gitignore`!

And in your code, you only use that file ***IF*** the env var isn't set. e.g.:

```js
// load auth & other tokens
var token = null;
if (process.env.hasOwnProperty('TOKEN')) {
  token = process.env.TOKEN;
}
else {
  var auth = require('./discordauth.json');
  token = auth.token;
}
```

From there you just have to learn how to set env vars in your particular hosting. Create an env var named `TOKEN` (to match `process.env.TOKEN` in the code example). Example:

Contents of file `discordauth.json`:

```js
{
"token": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
}
```

Value of env var `TOKEN`

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to expose secrets in your Github repo, you could use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to manage them locally. You store the secrets in a .env file at the root of your project. Make sure to remember to include .env in your .gitignore file so it doesn't get sent to version control.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine to store different client IDs and secrets for each environment inside of a GitHub repo (assuming that the repo is private). However, ideally you would store your client IDs and secrets for each of your environments inside of a **database table**. Then in your application itself you would simply reference said table (using the connection string for each environment) to retrieve the ID / secret pertaining to that specific environment.